# sort list by date in descending order - groovy madness

Tags: java, date, sorting, grails, groovy

I'm not able to sort a list of Objects by a Date in descending order

Let's say this is my class `Thing`

```
class Thing {

Profil profil
String status = 'ready'
Date dtCreated = new Date()
}
```

Inside the method I'm creating the `List things`

```
            List profiles = profil.xyz?.collect { Profil.collection.findOne(_id:it) }

            List things = []
```

and then I populate the list with each associated `Thing` of each profile

```
            profiles.each() { profile,i ->
                if(profile) {
                    things += Thing.findAllByProfilAndStatus(profile, "ready", [sort: 'dtCreated', order: 'desc']) as 
                 }
```

Alright, now `things` has a lot of things in it, unfortunately the  `[order: 'desc']` was applied to each set of things and iI need to sort the whole list by `dtCreated`. That works wonderful like

```
            things.sort{it.dtCreated}
```

Fine, now all the things are sorted by date but in the wrong order, the most recent thing is the last thing in the list

So I need to sort in the opposite direction, I didn't find anything on the web that brought me forward, I tried stuff like

```
            things.sort{-it.dtCreated} //doesnt work
            things.sort{it.dtCreated}.reverse() //has no effect
```

and I'm not finding any groovy approach for such a standard operation, maybe someone has a hint how I can sort my things by date in descending order ? There must be something like orm I used above  `[sort: 'dtCreated', order: 'desc']`
or isn't it?

Comment: `things.sort{-it.dtCreated.time}`

Comment: The minus sign only works if the value is a number.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Instead of

```
things.sort{-it.dtCreated}
```

you might try

```
things.sort{a,b-> b.dtCreated<=>a.dtCreated}
```

reverse() does nothing because it creates a new list instead of mutating the existing one.

```
things.sort{it.dtCreated}
things.reverse(true)
```

should work

```
things = things.reverse()
```

as well.

Comment: thank you so much, the first one woorks great for me, i tryed  things.reverse() before, not working for my case but things.reverse(true) is working thanks

Comment: also `reverseEach` if you wanna loop over it anyway afterwards.

Answer (score 7):

How about

```
things.sort{it.dtCreated}
Collections.reverse(things)
```

Look [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1015-Collections) for some more useful list utilities

Answer (score -8):

You may also use things.first() and things.last() to extract the first and the last element of the list.